# Firebase AppCheck - web app not working in debug mode

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-app-check

I have setup Firebase AppCheck for my Web App and everything seemed to work fine. Now I would like to enable the debug mode when developing my app.

I followed the instructions in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web-debug-provider#localhost) but I keep getting random errors from the AppCheck module, and these prevent my app from accessing Firebase Storage:

> ...at Backend FirebaseError: AppCheck: Fetch server returned an HTTP
> error status. HTTP status: 429. (appCheck/fetch-status-error).

Following the doc, this is the way I set AppCheck in debug mode - this is ran before everything else:

```
if(window.location.hostname == "localhost")
  self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;
```

Again, when my app is not in debug mode it works just fine.

Note 1: that I am not enforcing AppCheck via the console, and that 100% of the requests are displayed as "Verified"

[image]

Note 2: googling for "Firebase error 429" shows many results referring to some quota being exceeded, something hardly possible for my dev environment (we are 2 devs and definitely not putting in any sort of load on the app)

Comment: Getting the same thing

Comment: I added `localhost` to the trusted endpoints in the Google console. And note this is only a dev environment, dont do that for production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bug with the js library
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5052

Answer (score -1):

You should be using environment variables to detect debugging mode or not.
Depending on your framework and setup, this could be a command that you set up in your serve/build commands or a local env file that contains a specific debug key.

There is another issue if your reCaptcha is set to use localhost as the documentation states:

> Warning: Do not try to enable localhost debugging by adding localhost to reCAPTCHA’s allowed domains. Doing so would allow anyone to run your app from their local machines!

Comment: I dont care actually, it is just a dev environment. Of course I am not doing that with production

Comment: then why bother asking?

Comment: It is a workaround I found after this posting this question. Nevertheless the original issue remains....